Get Foreign Key id of a table and make a list of the object ids assigned to it in a JComboBox
I want to the admin user to select an Id from a MySql database table and show an id list of the other columns that are assigned to the original Id that the person selected in a JComboBox and JTextField(based id the person selected in the other combobox field). It is a Foreign Key that references to another table. I think it is easyer to understand looking at it than descrybing it:
visual description on what I'm trying to do
My DAO select operation is:
public Alarme[] obterAlarme() throws Exception{
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_timer";
        try (Connection conn = ConexaoBD.obterConexao(); PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql,
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY); ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

            int totalDeAlarmes = rs.last() ? rs.getRow() : 0;
            Alarme[] alarme = new Alarme[totalDeAlarmes];
            rs.beforeFirst();
            int contador = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                int idHabito = rs.getInt("fk_habito_id");
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String horaToque = String.valueOf(rs.getTime("hora_toque"));
                
                alarme[contador++] = new Alarme(idHabito, id, horaToque);
            }
            return alarme;
        }
    }

My JFrame methods:
public TelaAlarmes() {
        super("Alarme"); //class with constructors of the tb_timer fields
        initComponents();
        obterAlarmes();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

//this is initially assignning the "alarme" data to the foreign key field (not what I want, if you got it right)
private void obterAlarmes(){
        try {
            DAO dao = new DAO();
            Alarme[] alarme = dao.obterAlarme();
            cbbIdHabito.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(alarme));
        }
        
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alarmes indisponíveis. Tente novamente mais tarde!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


I think I would need to do another DAO operation and assign the values just as I did with the "cbbIdHabito" field, but I don't know how to do it properly.

You need to issue a JOIN query. No need for scrolling ResultSets - it's an unnecessary complication and expense. You'll then create a Map<String, Info> where the key is the ID and Info is the dependent row

Not clear what you are asking. From the image, looks like Hábito is a JComboBox. If it is, then how are you populating its list of values, i.e. its ComboBoxModel? Alarme also looks like a JComboBox. If so, then how are you populating its ComboBoxModel?
